# Why Reputation is Locked After a Serial Up-Voting?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-limit

On August 21st, I saw that I have -195 in my reputation page (See the picture below). It was written **voting corrected**. Then I checked out the [related help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) for it. I realized that I was a victim of serial up-voting. But after this event, my reputation did not seem to change when I got up-votes for my new question.

There is also another report of my reputation in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) provided by Martin Sleziak. This report is not the same as my reputation page on August 21st.

So I am curious to see what is happening!?

**The Report**

-- 2016-08-21 rep +25   = 7994
 1   1899246 (2)
 2   1896554 (5)
 2   1896554 (5)
 2   1900179 (5)
 2   1900179 (5)
 2   1900179 (5)
 2   1900179 (5)

**My Reputation Page**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the [daily reputation limit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-reputation-limit/info)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I think you are right! :) But the voting was corrected and I didn't get 195 reputations! So if it is due to this, then it is some kind of bug!

Comment: This might be related: [Serial Up-voting and Reputation Cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131795/serial-up-voting-and-reputation-cap).

Comment: Did you doublecheck that your reputation did not change or did you just note the absence of the green +10 indicator in the top-bar?

Comment: @quid:No, after the reversal, I should had +15 for three upvotes for my question but my reputation did not changed. I am sure about that the reputation did not change. :) I had the experience that sometimes the green +10 may not appear so I checked the reputation number. It is also evident in my reputation page if you check it out. :)

Comment: You were over the rep-cap when one includes the corrected votes. In that sense it is not that surprising.  What's strange though is that as I understand the answer linked by @MartinSleziak they should not count towards the cap.

Comment: @quid: Exactly! :)

Comment: When you check http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation, are the numbers shown there the same as in your profile?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I think they are not the same for the day this happened! :) I added the corresponding reputation page. It was on august 21st.

Comment: If they are not the same, perhaps you could include the part from the link corresponding to that day into your post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Done. :)

Comment: @H.R. I have also added link to [reputation tab in your profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/267844/h-r?tab=reputation). (In case other users want to check whether the situation is still the same as in your screenshot.) And I will also mention that I have asked one of the moderators about this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2016/8/26).

Comment: Okay, for some reason you had no recalc since the reversal, and thus your profile still thinks you were rep-capped that day. Let me see if I can trigger a recalc.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. :) I don't care about the points but just wanted to help find the reason that why recal did not happen! This issue may happen for other users in future! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yours was a bit of an edge case. The serial voting script runs early in the day (UTC, of course), and thus usually the votes it reverses are from the previous day. Then the reputation recalculation that happens on vote reversals finds out whether the reputation-cap kicked in and withheld reputation from other votes, and recalculates accordingly, so that afterwards it is as if "the serial upvotes never happened" - except that the entry in the reputation tab of the profile remains.

In your case, the serial voting occurred on the same day, before the script ran. When the script ran, you hadn't yet hit the reputation-cap, and for some reason, that led to the normal code still counting the votes towards the daily reputation-cap.

That's not a big problem, since on the next recalculation things are corrected. But when the next recalculation doesn't happen soon, the wrong reputation count persists for several days or even weeks.

You had no recalculation since the day of the serial voting, so the wrong score persisted until today. I triggered a recalculation by temporarily deleting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526104/computing-the-n-th-derivative-of-fxm) of yours (and then a new recalculation by undeleting it again).

In this way, one can trigger a recalculation oneself (provided one has eligible posts), deleting or undeleting a post triggers a recalculation (maybe not if the deletion/undeletion doesn't cause a reputation change), so by temporarily deleting or undeleting a post one can bring one's reputation up-to-date (it takes several minutes until the recalculation occurs, so one has to wait a bit before undoing the temporary [un]deletion).